# Adicionar legenda em um Mapa pela API do googlemaps

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma forma de adicionar legendas diretamente pela API do googlemaps ou você precisa colocar a legenda externa ao mapa,na documentação não achei nenhum exemplo de como fazer caso existe?
Legenda que eu digo é por exemplo:

> Amarelo-Significa um valor 10 Vermelhor-Significa valor 20 ...

Comment: Olá. Achei esse exemplo na documentação: https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/adding-a-legend?hl=pt

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

acho importante ter um exemplo aqui, segue abaixo:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(
    document.getElementById('legend'));
  
  var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    map: map,
    icon: "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GZzKwf6g1o8/S6xwK6CSghI/AAAAAAAAA98/_iA3r4Ehclk/s1600/marker-green.png"
  });

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.818038, -117.928492),
    map: map
  });
});
```

```css
#legend {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 5px !important;
  right: 5px !important;
}
.display-flex {
  display: flex;
}
.legend-box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_div" style="height: 400px;"></div>
<div id="legend">
  Legenda:
  <div class="display-flex"><div class="legend-box" style="background: #65BA4A;"></div> Ponto Inicial</div>
  <div class="display-flex"><div class="legend-box" style="background: #F76053;"></div> Ponto Final</div>
</div>
```

o principal é criar o `<div id="legend"></div>` com o conteúdo que deseja, e adicionar

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(
    document.getElementById('legend'));
```

para que o div fique dentro do mapa no canto superior direito, você pode mudar a constante `RIGHT_TOP` para outros valores como `RIGHT_BOTTOM`, `LEFT_TOP` e `LEFT_BOTTOM` e o `div` irá para o lugar determinado